# Plotting dataframe columns by similarity in header strings on one graph Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I have a dataframe that has 2 sets of data both with the same or similar names in their headers/column names.

The data looks something like this:

```
Cali_Lower_Population   Cali_Upper_Population    Cali_Lower_Density   Cali_Upper_Density    NY_Mid_Population
12000                   20000                    31222                21000                 3323232
14000                   20000                    41322                12000                 3323232
14300                   203420                   41222                10000                 3323232
12100                   30000                    11222                22000                 3323232
12400                   24000                    31222                23200                 3323232
11000                   22200                    21422                23000                 3323232
```

What I want to do is plot like-values on the strings after the second `'_'` for each column.

For Example: `Population` and `Density` I'd like to plot `Cali_Lower_Population`, `Cali_Upper_Population`, `NY_Mid_Population` and on *another* plot have `Cali_Lower_Density`, `Cali_Upper_Density`.

So then it would group by `_Population` and `_Density`because they are similar.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to filter your data frame like this:

```
df.filter(like='Population').plot()
df.filter(like='Density').plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Correct approach afaics, except OP searched for `like='Population'` and `like='Density'`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: This is good but if I had a variable list of things that didn't stay the same - ie: if instead of `Density` we had extra variables like `Temp` and `Heat` could I use a list to filter on of any given variable wanted by the input? So like `df.filter(like=[any element in this list])' ?

Comment: You could try using a regex like `df.filter(regex='(Population|Density|Temp|Heat)')`